# Splitting a string in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript

In ActionScript, you can pass in an empty delimiter for the `split` method and it will break the string up into an array, like so:

```
var myString:* = "Test";
var myArray:* = myString.split("");
// myArray contains "T", "e", "s", "t"
```

What I'm wondering is if the array is Unicode characters, containing 8 bytes or ASCII characters, containing 4 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: You're okay with the posted code because AS3 follows ECMAscript conventions same as JS but...) Another way to look at your code, the AS3 way...

> *`var`* *Variable-Name* **:** *`Type`* **=** *`Value;`*

```
var myString:String = "Test";
var myArray:Array = myString.split("");
// myArray contains "T", "e", "s", "t"
```

Arrays in AS3 are just that, a grouped collection of items! They can be Strings, Numbers or Bytes or whatever. A single `Array` object can have **mixed item types** at different indices.

You asked about **bytes** though so I hope you understand this `Array` result from "splitting" a String is not the same thing as a `ByteArray`. It's a "generic" array so to speak.

The default mode for Flash `String` seems to be Unicode/UTF-8 from experience. So technically you have 4 bytes until.. you decide to actually make a real byte array and **choosing how** you write the string as bytes will determine if you have 4 or 8 in the end...

```
var myString:String = "Test";
var myBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
myBytes.writeMultiByte( myString, "ASCII" );   //length = 4 bytes
myBytes.writeMultiByte( myString, "Unicode" ); //length = 8 bytes
```

PS: Flash considers both UTF-8 (4 bytes) and UTF-16 (8 bytes) as Unicode. Putting `"Unicode"` in the code makes it default to UTF-16 but you can set instead `"UTF-8"` to get a 4 bytes result..

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. As you can probably tell, I was confused about this lol.

Comment: Yeah I've been there myself. I've added a PS at the bottom of the answer. If you ever need to double-check: **[AS3 Supported Charsets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/charset-codes.html)**